# Does left-invariance imply right-invariance for closed unimodular normal subgroups?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have a locally compact group $G$ and a closed unimodular normal subgroup $N$.

Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $G$ which is left $N$-invariant.

Does it follow that $\mu$ is right $N$-invariant?

Answer (score 1):

<s>Yes.</s> This is true in the particular case when $\mu$ is a left Haar measure (i.e. is left $G$-invariant) — without assuming $\mu$ finite.

See Corollary B.1.7 in the book "Kazhdan's Property T" by Bekka-Harpe-Valette ([link at Bekka's page](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/bachir.bekka/KazhdanTotal.pdf)). In this setting, that $N$ is normal ensures that $G/N$ has a [Radon] invariant Borel measure, and since $N$ unimodular, the conclusion of the corollary is that the modular map $\Delta_G$ is trivial on $N$, which exactly means that the left Haar measure $\mu=\mu_G$ is right $N$-invariant.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow this argument. It seems that we are assuming $\mu$ is the Haar measure on $G$? But I am mostly interested in the cases where this is not so.

Comment: @Kim Indeed, I misread the question. I edited to say what I'm actually proving. Maybe one could then try the case when assuming that $\mu$ has density with respect to the Haar measure.

Comment: What about the case $G$ is compact and $N=G$? Does it follow that the measure $\mu$ necessarily the Haar measure? (since you don't assume $\mu$ to be outer or inner regular).